# Jenkins configuration for a project with local project dependencies

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a automation project which makes use of .jar of a util project. I am very new to Jenkins so can somebody guide me as to how to create a jenkin job and handle local project jar dependencies aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is jenkins pipeline you need to do the following.

1. Create a repo with a jenkinsfile*
2. Create a multi branch pipeline job in jenkins and point to your repo.
   When a build is started it will interpret your jenkinsfile and execute all the defined steps.

By making use of a .jar what do you mean? Is it an executable on the same machine? In that case add it to your path and use it when executing a shell or a bat script in the jenkinsfile.

More info here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

*Example jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent any

options {
    //Discard old builds, not necessary but nice to have
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30', artifactNumToKeepStr: '20'))
}

environment {
    // Example of how to retrieve credentials and set them as environment variables 
    EXAMPLE_CREDENTIAL= credentials('EXAMPLE_CREDENTIAL')
}

stages {
    stage('A build step') {
        steps {
          // do your stuff here, this can also be divided into several stages like one for building the code and one for executing it

        }
    }
}

// Post build actions, e.g archiving, clean up etc
 post {
    always {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/*.*', fingerprint: true
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Jan for your reply. What I meant is I have a project A with dependency of a local project B. So I need a jenkins job which will do "mvn clean install" for project B, and when execution of project A starts, the .jar of project B should be available for it. I dont know how??

Answer (score 0):

I would not build in dependencies to local projects. If it's just an executable .jar file you can add it as a secret file the same way you add credentials and while executing the job copy it to your workspace like this:

```
environment {
    FILE = credentials('my_file')
}

stages {
    stage('Preperation'){
        steps {
            // Copy your fie to the workspace
            sh "cp ${FILE} ${WORKSPACE}"
            // Verify the file is copied.
            sh "ls -la"
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative could be adding the file to your path and access the executable via the command line when executing the job.

If you want the whole project I would definitely check that out. I.e you need to add a a shell command for checking the project out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jan for your direction. I achieved output with the following code:

pipeline

```
agent any <br/>
stages {<br/>
    stage('Building dependent project') { <br/>
        steps {<br/>
            echo "Building dependent project"<br/>
    git (

             url: 'https:**********.git',
   credentialsId: '***********************',
   branch: "master"
  )

  sh "mvn clean install -DskipTests"

        }
    }
    stage('Building and testing main Project') { 
        steps {
              git (
             url: 'https://************.git',
   credentialsId: '******************',
   branch: "exp3" 
  )
  sh "mvn clean install -Dapp=${App} -Denv=${Envir} -Dversion=${Version}"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: But However, there is one more thing that I am unable to achieve. Attaching my extent report and mailing it to 5 people. Can you direct me how to achieve that. PS: I need to add that code in above pipeline. I have tried      publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: 'Reports', reportFiles: 'Extent_Report.html', reportName: 'GAP_Report', reportTitles: ''])
        it doesnt work.